# Suggestions for unit testing

Tags: unit-testing, fortran

Hello another question concerning debugging : Automatically generating test cases when i know the parameterset. And doing it all at once, instead during development (could kick myself)

i have a set of parameters for my software that i wish to test. (~ 12 parameters only). However of course these parameters are often integers, so for every parameter i can have 4 values that make sense(0, insanely huge, normally big, normally small).

is there a way i can generate my testcases automatically? would save me a lot of time. I already have to inspect every test case by hand, do i not? Alot of my program produces output to the console so normal assertions probably wont work, also i work on home made datastructures most of the time, so i could not use a simple assertion.

My dream option would be kind of a reverse regular expression, where i set the rules and get myself some file generated that i can use as an input (my software has a crude scripting language). that way i can assemble all input files and test them one by one.

Looking forward to listening to your kind suggestions.

cheers

Comment: Take a look at http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Unit+testing+frameworks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of ways to generate test cases in your scenario -- though you're a bit vague on what form the inputs for your programs and units need to take.  For one of my Fortran programs I use a template input parameter file, a bash script and a make file.  The make file, when called on the test phony target:

a) compiles the program;
b) runs the bash script, which uses sed to replace placeholders in the template parameter file, to create 128 (or whatever) test input files;
c) submits all the test jobs to the job management system on our cluster.

Once they jobs have finished I have some other scripts to compare outputs with benchmarks, collect statistics, that sort of thing.

If you need more specific advice, post more specific questions.

EDIT: Using sed inside a bash script:

Suppose that the parameter input template file contains 3 codes to be replaced: $FREQ$, $NUM$ and $TOL$.  Then I write a bash script with a 3-deep loop nest something like this:

```
for frq in 0.01 0.0 1 10
do
    for np in 1 2 4 8 16
    do
        for tol in 0.001 0.0001 0.00001
            sed ....
        done
    done
done
```

It's not pretty but it works, and it saves me wrestling with much more sophisticated solutions such as xUnit testing or Python programming.

Comment: that sounds like what i need. how do you do use sed to use a data basis? i was also looking for a "reverse" regex generator. so far unlucky

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read something about data-driven unit testing.

There are lots of frameworks that can help you with that.

You may start here: http://www.slideshare.net/dnastacio/datadriven-unit-testing-for-java-1933154.

Comment: hm isn't this a bit overkill? if there isnt at least a possibility to export all test cases into files, i would have to implement the whole framework in fortran again, since its java

Answer (score 1):

I see that you work with FORTRAN and you probably deal with one of FORTRAN's versions of xUnit. Being user of JUnit I'd suggest [parameterized tests](http://www.testearly.com/2007/04/13/take-heed-of-mixing-junit-4s-parameterized-tests/) - see if the concept applies in your case.

Comment: thanks i will read something about it, but will try the solution above